# How to calculate standard error for clogit output coefficients

Tags: r, standard-error

I have the output from a clogit funciton in R (see below) and I wish to find out the willingness to pay (WTP) and standard error of WTP for the different attributes by dividing the coefficients. In stata it is easy to achieve, using one line >nlcom but how do you do this in R? 
[image: clogit output]

Comment: Take a look at `svycontrast()` from the `survey` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer using the support.CEs package. Example code for calculating WTP in this example is:

```
mwtp(out.interactions, monetary.variables = c("PRICE"), nonmonetary.variables = c("GreenStatement", "Certification"),
 nreplications = 1000,
 confidence.level = 0.95,
 method = "delta")
```

Output will give you the mean wtp and confidence intervals